# How to input multidimensional array to a function in Python

Tags: python

```
def I_multilook(I, Az_look, Rg_look):
    N_az =int(np.floor((I.shape[0])/Az_look))
    N_rg =int(np.floor((I.shape[1])/Rg_look))
    b = np.zeros((N_az,N_rg), dtype=float)
    for i in range(1,N_az+1):
        for j in range (1,N_rg+1):
            b[(i-1),(j-1)]= np.mean(image[(i-1)*2:i*2,(j-1)*2:j*2]
          return b
```

When I am trying to return this shows return b invalid syntax, how to return this 2d array bfrom this function?

Comment: You have unmatched parentheses in the line before the return, and in any case your indentation is wrong (or at least, will be wrong once you've fixed the parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a closing bracket `)` to the end of the penultimate line (this is what's causing your error), and then either indent or unindent the final line.

Comment: *"either indent or unindent the final line"* - Clearly *unindent* it. Why would there be an unconditional `return` inside a loop (even if syntactically valid)?